# Facing searching issue in Solr I want to display matching record on the Top

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I am working on Smart Search and facing issue in searching my desired data are not display on Top I want to display left most data on top ,as display show in image facing issue [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxnja.png)
. Data has searched accurately but I want to display on Top with left most . 
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d2cG.png)

Comment: Are you thinking about phrase matching? Look at the `pf`, `pf2` and `pf3` parameters for the dismax and edismax handlers.

Comment: Thanks for response
actually dude when I am query some thing It show middle in the list and when I apply sorting then desired data is not show.

Comment: When you apply sorting, it'll have to match the sort you've added. You can use query elevation if you want to lift a particular document to the top for a specific query regardless of other factors.